# How to divide by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

I found a question in an old exam, where the function $\phi(z) := \frac{\exp(z) - 1}{z}$ is given.

Now we evaluate $\phi(\mathbf{A})$. But how do I divide by a matrix?

I already thought about taking the inverse, but how do I now on which side I have to multiply the inverse?

Comment: Notations can be misleading

Comment: I think you should note that some delicacy is required since: if A is singular the inverse doesn't exist but if you carry out the operations (exp(A)-1) and factor out A then you can hand wave and say A/A exists and is one.  There are also cases with infinite singular matrices where only the left hand inverse exists :)   Leading to more process ordering.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Note that applying function to a matrix is meant in sense of series, that is if
$$
\phi(z) = c_0 + c_1 z + c_2 z^2 + \dots
$$
then
$$
\phi(\mathbf A) = c_0 \mathbf I + c_1 \mathbf A + c_2 \mathbf A^2 + \dots.
$$
Observe that 
$$
\phi(z) = \frac{e^z - 1}{z} = 1 + \frac{z}{2} + \frac{z^2}{6} + \dots = 
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{z^{k-1}}{k!}.
$$
Also, to your question, dividing by a matrix is multiplying with its inverse, but that depends on commutativity, there's basically two ways to divide on a matrix - on the right and on the left. Luckily, a matrix commute with any power of itself, so there's no difference on which side do you write the $\mathbf A^{-1}$:
$$
\phi(\mathbf A) = \mathbf A^{-1} (e^\mathbf{A} - \mathbf I).
$$

Comment: Not OP, could you explain the last line? How does order never matter in that case?

Comment: @FarazMasroor it does not matter, since $A^{-1}$ commutes with every power of itself
$$
A^{-1} \left(A + \frac{A^2}{2} + \frac{A^3}{6} + \dots\right) = 
A^{-1}A + A^{-1}A \frac{A}{2} + I \frac{A^2}{6} + \dots = A A^{-1} + \frac{A}{2} AA^{-1} + \dots = \left(A + \frac{A^2}{2} + \frac{A^3}{6} + \dots\right) A^{-1}
$$
Note that $A^{-1}A = AA^{-1} = I$

Comment: Ah thanks, took me a bit to see.

Answer (score 10):

Note that since
$$
\exp(A)=I+A+\frac1{2!}A^2+\frac1{3!}A^3+\cdots
$$
then $A$ and $\exp(A)$ commute.

Thus also $\exp(A)-I$ and $A^{-1}$ commute.

Answer (score 5):

Try writing out the series for $exp$ and simplify the equation before you evaluate!

You wouldn't have to worry about dividing!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the series expansion of this function at $z=0$, you find there are only positive powers of $z$.

In any case, naively $\frac{1}{z}=z^{-1}$ just translates to the inverse, which exists for many matrices.

For all these translations, note, however, that $xy=yx$ need not hold for matrices. But if a function only involves one matrix variable ($z$ here), there is no problem.